# react-native: Platform specific style code only for android/ios

Tags: css, react-native

I need a particular style to apply only for android and needs to have no effect when on iOS.

My code snippet is somewhat like this:

```
<CardItem
  style={{
borderWidth: 0,
borderLeftWidth: 0,
borderRightWidth: 0,
borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
borderTopRightRadius: 10,
borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
backgroundColor: "#fff",
overflow: Platform.OS == "ios" ? "hidden":"auto"
}}
cardBody
>
```

I need the **overflow to be hidden only on iOS** and needs no effect when on android. I have used `overflow: Platform.OS == "ios" ? "hidden":"auto"`, but this doesn't look apt for the scenario.

Comment: so you want to remove overflow property for android?

Comment: Would this work for you `overflow: Platform.OS == "ios" && "hidden"`

Comment: I guess it might be because after backgroundColor is no comma, try to put there comma and see if it works

Comment: @Zirek good catch :)

Comment: @JaydeepGalani Yes!

Comment: @Zirek it was just a copy/paste error..fixed it now..hehe

Comment: @VilleKoo Got the error=> **Error while updating property 'overflow' in shadow node of type: RCTView
"Value for overflow cannot be cast from Boolean to String"**

Answer (score 3):

Overflow property doesn't have `auto` value on react-native. That's enum and has these:

> enum('visible', 'hidden', 'scroll')

set visible instead of auto for android. (that's default value)

```
overflow: Platform.OS == "ios" ? "hidden": "visible"
```

should work.